# Is it appropriate to reopen a post to move some content from the question to an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

The story begins over half a year ago, when I was still a new user and was not fully acquainted with the rules and culture of the site.

I asked a question, and as luck would have it, received a great answer to it. The user's answer inspired me to do a lot more digging and research to write my *own* answer. Unfortunately, being a new user at the time, I did not think it appropriate to answer my own question (for whatever reason), and so added the "answer" as an edit at the end of my question.

The following day, it was appropriately identified and marked as a duplicate of another question. Everything is fine upto this point.

Earlier today, I happened upon the question again, as I was looking through my question history. I noticed the "answer" sitting at the bottom of my question, and did not feel it was appropriate. At this point, I had 3 options:

1. Leave the question alone (allowing the "answer" to sit at the bottom of the question)
2. Edit the "answer" out the question, thereby deleting it
3. Move the "answer" to its own answer and COMMUNITY WIKI it, as it should've been to begin with

Option 1 did not sit well with me, as it never should've been in the question body to begin with.

Option 2 seemed the most sensible, but if I were to respect the efforts of 6-month-old me, that wouldn't sit well with me (in that sense, Option 1 would've been better).

Option 3 would involve reopening and closing the question. Now, I am well aware that reopening questions that should be closed to begin with is textbook abuse of one's gold badge. However, you should note that the "answer" was always *there*, just not in its own post. Also, I am the OP, the question isn't really popular, and I'd be CW'ing it anyway, so there are virtually no chances of repfarming this for personal gain.

I ended up going with Option 3. I initially forgot to CW the answer, but eventually did it after a subsequent edit. The question is now closed.

Was this an appropriate thing to have done? If not, what would've been the best thing to do in this scenario?

> This meta post is specific to one of *my* questions, and I'm not sure how applicable the answer to this question would be to a general scenario. As such, for your consideration, here is the link to the question: [Byte code of a compiled script differs based on how it was compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727740/byte-code-of-a-compiled-script-differs-based-on-how-it-was-compiled), hidden to avoid the Meta Effect.

Comment: Couldn't you answer the duplicate?

Comment: @rene I... honestly did not think of doing that! Though, if you consider the fact that Martijn's answered it, I think it would be better off not posting it at all... ha

Comment: Well, I give you that thou shall not annoy the Martijn but if you care so much  about that answer it would have been the path of least resistance

Comment: @rene Right... would it still be appropriate to move it out to the duplicate after all this?

Comment: We generally like to have canonical questions that have answers. If your answer adds something that isn't (fully) covered in Martijn's answer, then it adds value and is best added to the dupe target. But I'm not a Python dev so I can't judge the merits of your answer or that of Martijn.

Comment: @rene Thanks. The initial "answer" was written in the context of the question I asked. Moving it to some other question would definitely require some changes before it can be posted there, at the very least.

Comment: I wonder if your question was truly a duplicate then if you have this much resistance to posting your answer in the dupe target. apparently there is a contextual difference, it's not a 1:1 dupe.

Comment: _"hidden to avoid the Meta Effect"_ -- the only way to avoid "the Meta Effect" is to not include the link in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to reopen a post to move some content from the question to an answer?

No, I would think not.

> 3. Move the "answer" to its own answer…
>
> Option 3 would involve reopening and closing the question

As noted in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362358/is-it-appropriate-to-reopen-a-post-to-move-some-content-from-the-question-to-an?cb=1#comment551017_362358), you can achieve Option 3 without reopening your own question. Having been closed as a duplicate of another, you can post any relevant answer to the duplicate (or if that's closed, to *its* duplicate, and so on…).

And in general, that would be the appropriate mechanism. Your question might be left undeleted as a "signpost", but otherwise as a closed question it's considered inactive and should remain such unless there's a reason to dispute the closure itself. If there's no dispute about the closure, keep the question closed, even if that blocks some other action you want to take.

Now, in this case, there's a question in your mind about whether the answer you posted could be appropriately posted as an answer to the duplicate, at least without significant changes. And [someone else opines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362358/is-it-appropriate-to-reopen-a-post-to-move-some-content-from-the-question-to-an?cb=1#comment551103_362358) that perhaps that means your question wasn't really a duplicate after all.

You didn't ask, but it seems worthwhile to me to explore that aspect of the situation.

As an eager duplicate-close-voter myself, I am sympathetic to Martijn's choice to close your question as a duplicate. Many questions appear poorly researched, and as long as a duplicate target provides sufficient information to answer the question, even if the questions aren't literally the same, a duplicate-close can IMHO be appropriate.

I would say that's the case here. Had you researched how to *correctly* interpret .pyc files, you likely would even have found Martijn's answer and come to the same conclusion yourself.

That said, your question is not *literally* the same as the marked duplicate, nor does the marked duplicate actually *answer* your question. That is, your actual question appears to be this:

> Why is there such a stark contrast in the byte code depending on how it was compiled?

Granted, your question is worded incorrectly, because it makes the incorrect assumption that you have in fact decompiled it correctly, when you haven't. But taken literally, the only correct answer would be to explain *your* mistake specifically. Which Martijn's answer does not.

So there's a subjectively valid argument in favor of reopening your question, disputing the as-duplicate closure. And regardless, answering that literal question would be very much out-of-place on the duplicate question. It just wouldn't make sense, because that's not really what the duplicate question asked.

That said, personally, I'd probably have left your question closed and not even bothered with your answer. The answer you posted (originally included in your question) is really just a restatement of the answer you'd already gotten anyway. It adds little to nothing to the whole page.

Furthermore, your question itself is very narrowly constructed, and specific to a unique misunderstanding of .pyc files. Inasmuch as Stack Overflow is primarily here to accumulate a storehouse of useful programming knowledge for the benefit of future readers, the likelihood of your question ever actually being directly useful to someone else seems low.

To me, it's akin to something like:

> I have the following C program:
>
> ```
> int a = 5, b = 7, c = a + b;
> ```
>
> Why doesn't `c` wind up with the value 35?

I mean, there's a simple, direct answer to it. But the question exists only to the extent of there being an incorrect assumption about what the code means in the first place.

People, especially people new to a language, make such incorrect assumptions all the time. But each time, they do so in a completely novel way, and while it's nice to help those people out, questions like that don't really need to stick around for the benefit of others. The odds of anyone else making that *precise* incorrect assumption are slim to none, and even if they do, the odds of them being able to find that particular Q&A are even smaller.

In that respect, the answer to the broader question ["How can I understand a .pyc file content?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32562163) does in fact seem appropriate. I.e. while it doesn't answer your literal question, it answers the question you actually needed an answer to, and in fact is the answer you should have found (whether the failure to do so was lack of attempt, or simply a failing in the Stack Overflow search feature).

And since the answer you posted to your own question (originally added to the question itself, but then later moved to be an answer in its own right) says basically the same thing as the actual answer you received from someone else, it doesn't seem to be adding anything new and can safely be just left out altogether.